# How to reload the conditional rendering in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    <div className="confessions-container">
        <div className="search-confession">
            <form className="search-form">
                <div className="form-control">
                        <label htmlFor="categories">Category</label>
                        <select name="categories" ref={refCategory} onChange={() => setCategory(refCategory.current.value)}>

                            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                            {categories.map((category) => {
                                return (
                                    <option value={category}>{category}</option>
                                )
                            })}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-control search">
                        <input type="text" name="title" ref={refSearch}/>
                        <button className="btn-search">Search</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>


        {category ? <ConfessionByCategory category={category} /> :  <AllConfessions />}
        
        

    </div>
```

if i change the category(from the select) for the first time the conditional rendering runs. but if i change to a different category it wont rerender

Comment: Can you add your `onChangeCategory` handler code?

Comment: onChangeCategory has setCategory(refCategory.current.value)

Comment: is there any reason you're using refs instead of just doing the event value? `onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}`

Comment: no, but I have already tried that way, but it doesnt work the way i want it to

Comment: can you show your full component, cause it seems that nothing wrong with this snippet

Comment: i know there's nothing wrong in my code. what i want to know is for example, if I select a category page reloads showing the only category i selected. but if i change the category again. it doesnt do anything